# Triple for loop for a data set

Tags: python, performance

I am writing a triple `for` loop in Python. Since the data set is larger, it takes more than 1.5 hours to finish. Is there any fast way to avoid the loop?

```
idx = []
for key, value in bid_img.iteritems():
    for v in value:
        loc = 0
        for pid in pid_lst:
            loc += 1
            if v == pid:
                idx.append(loc)
```

---

What I have:

1. `bid_img` a dictionary that contain multiple values per key.
2. `pid_lst` a list.

I want to index items for values in dic, if they match with list provided, then store them in `idx` and `loc` for index.

Sample input:

```
bid_img = {'123': ['4123','12312','1231234'], '2312':['413','112','12334']};
```

Sample output:

```
idx = [5, 11,62, 32]
```

1. The input is larger than \$10^6\$.
2. The order of output is very important; I want the exact order.
3. I want to find the index or location (for each value in dict) in list `pid_lst`.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: Thanks! Does my summarization meet the community standard? Anything I can improve?

Comment: But `big_img` is a dictionary, and `iteritems()` on a dictionary doesn't guarantee any particular order. Can you please explain your motivation further?

Comment: Are the values in the bid_img dictionary sorted? And do you care about duplicates? 
If the values are sorted using binary search to find the values of pid_lst in the values array could be faster than doing a linear search through both arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the outer loop can be optimised. You're using

```
for key, value in bid_img.iteritems():
```

But `key` is unused. Suggestion:

```
for value in bid_img.itervalues():
```

The inner loop can be optimised as well:

```
    loc = 0
    for pid in pid_lst:
        loc += 1
        if v == pid:
            idx.append(loc)
```

Suggestion:

```
    for loc, pid in enumerate(pid_lst, start=1):
        if v == pid:
            idx.append(loc)
```

The repeated calls to `idx.append` can be costly. Why not:

```
    idx.extend(loc for loc, pid in enumerate(pid_lst, start=1) if v == pid)
```

(Hope I didn't make any typo's, typing from my phone)